# Simplify LaTeX document to satisfy editing office

Tags: glossaries, siunitx, acronyms, journal-publishing

I have a LaTeX manuscript prepared using a publisher class file (`agutex`) where I've used four packages (`booktabs`, `glossaries`, `siunitx`, `graphicx`).  I use glossaries in particular for acronyms.  After submission, the editing office has replied that they have problems with all my packages, and that I am not allowed to use any custom commands.  Is there any tool to “downgrade” the LaTeX document, such as automatically replacing each occurence of `\gls` by the appropiate text (acronym with or without expansion), and similarly for `siunitx`?

It would be a bit painful to do this by hand.

Comment: Perhaps you should have asked your publisher or read the author guide (if available) *before* inserting all the forbidden stuff.

Comment: It sounds like they have a *very* old TeX distribution if they don't even have `graphicx`!

Comment: this could be done with `perl`

Comment: What about removing packages the editing office refused and using  `\newcommand` to define specials commands which don't work anymore like `\gls` ?

Comment: @ppr not allowed to use any custom commands

Comment: I suggest murder followed by burning down the publishers office and wiping their servers.

Comment: Well, they weren't specific about what problems they had with the packages.  They do not forbid packages overall...  I've removed by '\newcommand' issues (which was easy by text-and-replace) and hope it will be fine now, or I should ask for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this script to rid my manuscript of all `\gls` and `\glspl` occurences, and replace them by acronyms using a very simple algorithm.  Some editing was still needed afterwards.  The script is quick and dirty.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.2

f_in = "manuscript.tex"
f_out = "manuscript_mod.tex"
lines = open(f_in).readlines()
acros = dict([(w[1][:-1], w[3].strip()[:-1]) for w in [line.split('{') for line in
                lines if line.startswith(r"\newacronym")]])
had = dict.fromkeys(acros, False)
with open(f_out, 'w') as fp:
    for line in lines:
        if r"\glsresetall" in line:
            had = dict.fromkeys(acros, False)
        if line.startswith("%"):
            fp.write(line)
            continue
        for m in ("gls", "glspl"):
            pl = ("s" if "pl" in m else "")
            ln = 7 if "pl" in m else 5
            while "\\" + m + "{" in line:
                print("Working on: " + line)
                strt = line.find("\\" + m + "{")
                end = line.find("}", strt)
                acr = line[strt+ln:end]
                if had[acr]:
                    line = line[:strt] + acr + pl + line[end+1:]
                else:
                    line = line[:strt] + acros[acr] + pl + " (" + acr + pl + ")" + line[end+1:]
                    had[acr] = True
        fp.write(line)
```